# Network Rejoin Powershell Script Failing to Connect to the preferred Wi-Fi Network

Tags: powershell, netsh, network-connection

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will attempt to check to see if a workstation is connected to the Internet, if its not, attempt to connect to 1 of 3 different known Wi-Fi networks, repeat on loop every 5 minutes.

When I attempt to run my script, the script not only doesn't actually connect to any of the preferred networks, but will say that I'm connected to a preferred network even if I'm not connected to any Wi-Fi network. The script works as intended if it is connected to preferred network.

I may just have a fundamental misunderstanding of my own code.

**Task scheduler is not an option as when the computer disconnects from the wi-fi, there is no 'Network Disconnect' event generated. See below for reason.**

Justification for needing a script like this is that the workstation is in a place where a hardline connection cannot be ran. There is a group policy membership on the workstation that periodically disconnects the device from the wi-fi (This is why there is no 'Network Disconnect' event generated), and the computer needs to remain connected to the wi-fi as it has to gather information from internet constantly. Removing the workstation from that group is not an option either.

```
Import-Module -Name BurntToast -Global

# Define the preferred network SSIDs
$preferredNetworks = @("Network1", "Network2", "Network3")

# Get the list of currently connected networks
$connectedNetworks = Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Check if already connected to a preferred network
$alreadyConnected = $connectedNetworks | Where-Object { $_ -in $preferredNetworks }

function Test-InternetConnection {
    try {
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.google.com")
        $request.Timeout = 10000
        $request.Method = "HEAD"

        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $response.Close()

        return $true
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}

while ($true) {
    if (-not (Test-InternetConnection)) {
        $connectedNetworks = Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $alreadyConnected = $connectedNetworks | Where-Object { $_ -in $preferredNetworks }

        if ($alreadyConnected) {
            # Output that the device is already connected to a preferred network and exit
            Write-Output "Device is already connected to a preferred network: $alreadyConnected"
            New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Already Connected", "Device is already connected to a preferred network: $alreadyConnected"
        }

        # If not connected to a preferred network, continue with the script to scan and connect
        $availableNetworks = netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid | Select-String -Pattern "SSID\s+\d+\s+:\s+(.+)" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim() }

        # Find a preferred network that is available
        $networkToConnect = $availableNetworks | Where-Object { $_ -in $preferredNetworks }

        if ($networkToConnect) {
            # Attempt to connect to the found network
            foreach ($network in $networkToConnect) {
                Write-Output "Attempting to connect to $network"
                netsh wlan connect name=$network
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 # Wait for a few seconds to establish connection

                # Check connection status again
                $currentConnection = Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
                if ($currentConnection -eq $network) {
                    Write-Output "Successfully connected to $network"
                    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Connection Successful", "Successfully connected to $network"
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    else{
        $connectedNetworks = Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $alreadyConnected = $connectedNetworks | Where-Object { $_ -in $preferredNetworks }

            # Output that the device is already connected to a preferred network and exit
            Write-Output "Device is already connected to a preferred network: $alreadyConnected"
            New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Already Connected", "Device is already connected to a preferred network: $alreadyConnected"
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
    }
}
else {
    Write-Output "None of the preferred networks are available."
    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Network Connection Failure", "Failed to Connect to a preferred network. Please Contact IT if you're unable to manually connect to a network."
}
```

Above is my powershell script. What I have tried is to flip the logic, for example if 'Test-InternetConnection' returns true, then to do the inverse. I've tried to go outside of the while loop to run 'Test-InternetConnection' and still I get the same issue, not connected, yet the script is saying I am.

What I'm expecting to happen is that the script will check to see if 'Test-InternetConnection' returns false, if so, loop through each of the preferred connection and make a connection request. (I plan to implement additional logic that will check to see if any of the connections were successful before attempting to go to the next.) If it returns true AND if the network currently connected to is one of the prefered networks, shoot down to the Start-Sleep for 5 minutes.

Comment: IP uses routing or machine name.   The machine name uses DHCP to get route from a server. There is no mechanism to specify a route on a window machine.  Routing takes the best route based on the mask.  The best route is the most specific route based on the mask.